# Adding Axis2 to a Spring-Roo application

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, spring-roo

Is it possible to add Axis2 to a Spring-Roo designed web app to add a web service interface.

I have an admin interface defined which connects to a database.  This has all been done easily using Spring ROO, however, I need to add a web service interface to it, and was going to add this using Axis2, however, I can't work out how to put the two together.

Is this possible, and if so, can anyone supply some pointers, examples or links to a tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

gvNIX project includes a Roo addon called service-layer. It provides support for WebServices. Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/gvnix/wiki/gvNIX_0_6_0_released

Hope it helps.